# Django - How to reset model fields to their default value?

Tags: django, django-models

What would be the most elegant\efficient way to reset all fields of a certain model instance back to their defaults?

Comment: I think I may have mis-understood your question - are you wanting to set each field to the "default" value coded for each field object on the model - or set each field back to what it was before the value of the field was modified?

Comment: @Matthew - the prior. If I would have wanted the latter I would you django-reversion.

Answer (score 8):

I once did it this way. No better way I could think of.

```
from django.db.models.fields import NOT_PROVIDED

for f in instance._meta.fields:
    if f.default <> NOT_PROVIDED:
        setattr(instance, f.name, f.default)

# treatment of None values, in your words, to handle fields not marked with null=True
...
...
# treatment ends

instance.save()
```

Note: In my case all the fields, did have default value.

Hope it'll help. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 4):

```
def reset( self, fields=[], exclude=[] ):

    fields = fields or filter( lambda x: x.name in fields, self._meta.fields )
    exclude.append( 'id' )        

    for f in filter( lambda x: x.name not in exclude, fields ):
        if getattr( f, 'auto_now_add', False ):
            continue

        if f.blank or f.has_default():
            setattr( self, f.name, f.get_default() )
```

Comment: This has a bug from using [] as a default parameter.  You're modifying the same list over and over adding 'id' to it.  https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Answer (score 2):

This method is mainly applicable for resetting a single value to a default, but can be adapted. It resets the `rego_update` property for all my `Event` objects.

```
Event.objects.all().update(rego_update=Event().rego_update)
```

Alternatively, to apply it individually (i.e. to trigger custom `save` methods):

```
default = Event().rego_update  # Hack to fetch the default
for event in Event.objects.all():
    event.rego_update = default
    event.save()
```

To adapt this to reset all values for a single instance, you could manually reset each value with a default.

Alternatively, you could loop through the attributes similar to other answers here, but this will have issues with fields that have no default (or cannot be edited).

Comment: Your solution's verbosity is obviously better than mine! Clever ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assign `None` to the fields, and save.

Comment: Wouldn't that work only in a subset of situations? For instance, would it work for fields not marked with blank=True and null=True?

Comment: Database inserts or updates of NULL are changed to the field's default value.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm pretty sure that you're right. Why would Django even have `null = True` fields if they just become default values?

Answer (score 0):

After you've made changes to that instance but before you've "saved" it, I assume?  I think you'll probably need to re-retrieve it from the database...  I don't think that Django model instances keep a "history" of changes that have been made to an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assign None to all fields that are not nullable, by checking the `.null` field attribute:

```
for name, value in {f.name: None for f in self._meta.fields if f.null}:
    setattr(instance, name, value)
instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.your_field =self.__class__._meta.get_field('your_field').default`.

Please note you should wrap this into a try/except while depending on your django's version `get_field` might get some other name

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create a blank model instance and then update the current one with it, like this:

```py
def reset(self):
    new_instance = type(self)()
    self.__dict__.update(new_instance.__dict__)
```

or if you want to keep the model id:

```py
def reset(self):
    new_instance = type(self)(id=self.id)
    self.__dict__.update(new_instance.__dict__)
```